# Remove elements from a certain positions

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file with three columns. From some of the rows I want to delete an element in the third column. I have also a list with number of lines, from which I want to delete the third element.

My file looks like :

```
2.34 5.3974 8.202847
8.271 6.294 9.04
9.2846 5.847 1.372
```

My list of line numbers:

```
2
3
```

The desire output:

```
2.34 5.3974 8.202847
8.271 6.294 
9.2846 5.847
```

When I had a small files, I just used:`awk '{if (NR==2 || NR==3) $3=""; print}' file`.
But this solution doesn't work, if I had ~1500 lines to change. How is it possible to do using bash and awk (or sed)?
I would appreciate every suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is that you save the line numbers in a file say `lines` and use `awk` to read through that file and the input file to filter out the lines.

**Example**

```
$ cat lines
2
3
$ awk 'FNR==NR{line[$0]++; next} FNR in line{$3=""}1' lines file
2.34 5.3974 8.202847
8.271 6.294
9.2846 5.847
```

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: @MirrG Glad to hear it helped :)